# Shortest Path Program, Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, path-finding

I'm doing a project for my schools robotics team. I need to find a way to find the shortest route between a starting point, three parking lots, and an ending point. This is what I have so far:

```
d = {'A': ['B'], #Block1
         'B': ['R', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'X' 'H'],
         'C': ['D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'X', 'H'],
         'D': ['I', 'Q', 'P', 'O', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'X', 'H'],
         'E': ['F', 'Q', 'G', 'X', 'H'],
         'F': ['Q', 'P', 'G', 'X', 'H'],
         'G': ['Q', 'O', 'I', 'X', 'H'],
         'H': ['V', 'I'],
         'I': ['J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'W'],
         'J': ['K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'W', 'P', 'H', 'G'],
         'K': ['L', 'M', 'N', 'W', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'f'],
         'L': ['M', 'N', 'W', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'E'],
         'M': ['N', 'W', 'O', 'T', 'P', 'Q', 'D'],
         'N': ['W', 'O', 'Q', 'C'],
         'O': ['D', 'L', 'K', 'J', 'G'],
         'P': ['G', 'F', 'K', 'L', 'D', 'M', 'Z'],
         'Q': ['N', 'S', 'M', 'D', 'L', 'E', 'K', 'U', 'F', 'J', 'G', 'H'],
         'R': ['B'], #Parking Lot
         'S': ['Q'], #Parking Lot
         'T': ['M'], #Parking Lot
         'U': ['Q'], #Parking Lot
         'V': ['H'], #Parking Lot
         'W': ['A'],
         'X': ['H'], #block2
         'Z': ['Q']}


def find_shortest_path(d, start, end, path=[]):
    path = path + [start]
    if start == end:
        return path
    if not d.has_key(start):
        return None
    shortest = None
    for node in d[start]:
        if node not in path:
            newpath = find_shortest_path(d, node, end, path)
            if newpath:
                if not shortest or len(newpath) < len(shortest):
                    shortest = newpath
    return shortest

x = find_shortest_path
```

Right now, it is able to plot a path from start to end, now I need to get it to stop at three specified spots. I have no idea how to do this, though. I could use any help, or if you have any suggestions to improve my code. I understand it may be messy, but I just need it to work. Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain the structure of `d`? Also, small thing, but the last line needs to pass some parameters to `find_shortest_path`.

Answer (score 1):

As you know already how to find the way between
two points, you can use it to find the way from the start point to the
first specific spot, then from there to the next etc.

If you do not know the best order of visiting the three spots and
need in all cases the shortest way, you can try all 3!=3*2*1=6 combinations and then choose the shortest.

Comment: Well, the spots aren't given in a certain order to go to, I need to find the shortest path to go from start to end, while hitting all three.

Comment: @JacobGarry I extended my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion is to add a list of stops (call it A) as input and run a test to see if they are all reached before allowing the rest of find_shortest_path to proceed.  One such test may be to add arrived required stops to a list (call it B) and check if B = A before proceeding to line 3 of find_shortest_path()'s definition.